# ImageMagick: Cropping out sides and irregular borders to get a straight rectangular result

Tags: imagemagick

I have images like this. White border and a polygonal-ish swatches-like slanted-sides "inset" pictures in the middle with always four sides, although of varying side-angles, sizes and proportions

(Please note that these (examples) images are not the real images but I've made them to illustrate the exact sources I'll be working with.)

### SOURCE IMAGES:

***(The thick gray outlines are NOT part of the images below. I've added the gray outline just to make the original images stand out against stackoverflow pages' white background)***

[image] [image]

### PROCESSING DIAGRAM

I want to crop out the sides (including the outside white)...

[image] [image]

### DESIRED RESULT

... so that I end up with a perfect largest possible straight-sided cropped rectangle from inside, and with no white around it, like so:

[image] [image]

I need to do this for images which will have different irregular insets, like these examples, in both portrait and landscape orientation.

(Other images will have different slants and the amount of white background border will vary, BUT will always have only four corners). So I'd need an adaptive, dynamic solution.

I was thinking, could it be possible by calculating white pixels of the four corners somehow, then cropping the sides one by one using the corner coordinates. The borders will be white, but the images are all jpegs so some "fuzz" percentage might be needed.

I've tried to do it by calculating white pixels from corners, but am struggling at how or what should be my steps in achieving that.

Can it be done?

(I'm on windows, with ImageMagick 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick (6.9.12-54 or higher) using a special define for -trim.

*(Some bugs have been found and fixed for -trim, so use the latest version of Imagemagick)*

Image:

[image]

```
convert bubbles.jpg -background white -define trim:percent-background=0% -trim +repage result.jpg
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you , but this only removes the homogeneous white background, while stilling retaining uneven white around? 

I would like to crop it beyond the borders of the inside image, extracting the largest possible rectangle from within.  (Other images will have different slants and the amount of white background border will vary, BUT will always have only four corners).  So I'd need an adaptive, dynamic solution.

I was thinking, could it be possible by calculating white pixels of the four corners somehow, then cropping the sides one by one using the corner coordinates? Can it be done? Thx!!

Comment: @spcsLrg If you have images for which this answer doesn't work, please edit your post and add them. Also, please don't forget to upvote helpful answers. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sorry about that. I've now added more illustrative images (as examples) and more description to the question too. I hope it makes it clearer than before. Please note that these (examples) images are not the real images but I've made them to illustrate the exact sources I'll be working with. I'll have many more images which I can't all include with the post. Thank you. I will include this note in the Q too.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see why it does not work if you do not have the gray border. Please post the two images without the gray borders.  I would think the same command above would work for both images.

Comment: @fmw42 OK, may be I'm doing something wrong.  I get these two results after running the commands for the two images in the question, respectively: https://i.postimg.cc/25kPc4Ws/result.jpg and https://i.postimg.cc/RhdtRxz5/result2.jpg  Thanks!

Comment: Did you remove the gray background?  What version of Imagemagick are you using? You need 6.9.12-54 or higher, but some versions may have had bugs. So use the current version if possible. If on Imagemagick 7, use magick in place of convert. Sorry, I do not know what version IM 7 is required. Probably 7.1.0.41

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, I ran IM 7.0..8 on the images without the borders. (I had added the borders just for this question on SO, as a dark background to prevent the image's white from blending into the page bg) Yes, I ran the commands without `convert` and just with `magick`. Should I get v 7.1.0.41?

Comment: Please clarify your IM version.  You are missing a digit. If less than 7.1.0.41, then upgrade to the latest.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes!!! v 7.1.0.41 did it! Thank you so much! My bad all along afterall! :D Am marking this as solved! Cheers! (Mine was 7.0.1.8 I think).